# Group by multiple fields using Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Given I have following data:

```
| Date | Value |Count|
| 2021-01-01 | X | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | X | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | Y | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | X | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | X | 2 |
| 2021-02-02 | Y | 5 |
```

I want to group by these data using multiple fields. ( Date and Value ).

```
   Example :  Data.GroupBy(x=> new { x.Date, x.Value });
```

Expected Result :

```
| Date | Value | Count |
| 2021-01-01 | X | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Y | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | X | 3 |
| 2021-02-02 | Y | 5 |
```

How can I execute this query using Nest?

Updated :

Index Mapping :

```
{
  "samples" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "count" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "value" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You added index by ``Nest`` or explicitly added in ``Kibana`` dashboard? because when add by ``Nest`` you can set ``NumberOfShards`` for index.

Comment: I added index using Nest

Comment: It's hard to guess whats happening. you can use ``EnableDebugMode`` on elastic connection to see what exactly problem is and you can see the debug message in exception.

Comment: I enabled debug mode and the message is : Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. I fixed this problem before using Suffix('keyword') But I don't know what is the equivalent of Suffix('keyword') in script queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue one month ago, Let's assume your class is like this:

```
 public class Sample
  {
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
  }
```

And the final result is like this:

```
 public class Report
  {
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public double? SumCount { get; set; }
  }
```

And search on elastic:

```
public async Task<List<Report>> GetReportAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var result = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Sample>(search => search
                .Aggregations(agg => agg
                    .Terms("result", t => t
                        .Script(sc => sc.Source("doc['date'].value+'#'+doc['value'].value").Lang(ScriptLang.Painless))
                        .Aggregations(a => a
                            .Sum("SumCount", s => s.Field(f => f.Count))
                        )))
                .Source(false)
                .Size(0), token);

            return result.Aggregations.Terms("result").Buckets.Select(x => new Report
            {
                Date = x.Key.Split(new[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0],
                Value = x.Key.Split(new[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1],
                SumCount = ((ValueAggregate)x["SumCount"])?.Value
            }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Query returns 400 BadRequest Error : Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /samples/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi Cloud you share how you add data to elastic? the error is about how you define index and how map model to elastic.

Comment: I added index mapping to the question.

Comment: I fixed the problem with change doc['value'].value to doc['value.keyword'].value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In versions of Elasticsearch 6.1 onwards, a [Composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) is the right choice for this

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var default_index = "tmp";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(default_index);
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.Indices.Exists(default_index).Exists)
        client.Indices.Delete(default_index);
    
    client.Indices.Create(default_index, c => c
        .Map<Tmp>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
        )
    );

    client.IndexMany(new [] 
    {
        new Tmp("2021-01-01", "X", 1),
        new Tmp("2021-01-01", "X", 2),
        new Tmp("2021-01-01", "Y", 1),
        new Tmp("2021-02-02", "X", 1),
        new Tmp("2021-02-02", "X", 2),
        new Tmp("2021-02-02", "Y", 5)
    });

    client.Indices.Refresh(default_index);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Tmp>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Composite("composite", t => t
                .Sources(so => so
                    .DateHistogram("date", d => d.Field(f => f.Date).FixedInterval("1d").Format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    .Terms("value", t => t.Field(f => f.Value))
                )
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .Sum("composite_count", su => su
                        .Field(f => f.Count)
                    )   
                )
            )
        )
    );
    
    Console.WriteLine("| Date | Value | Count |");
    foreach (var bucket in searchResponse.Aggregations.Composite("composite").Buckets)
    {
        bucket.Key.TryGetValue("date", out string date);
        bucket.Key.TryGetValue("value", out string value);
        var sum = bucket.Sum("composite_count").Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"| {date} | {value} | {sum} |"); 
    }
}

public class Tmp 
{
    public Tmp(string date, string value, int count)
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(date);
        Value = value;
        Count = count;
    }
    
    public Tmp()
    {
    }
    
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    
    [Keyword]
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}
}
```

prints

```
| Date | Value | Count |
| 2021-01-01 | X | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Y | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | X | 3 |
| 2021-02-02 | Y | 5 |
```